# Submit form to iframe

Tags: html

So i'm submiting form with jquery to ifram like this `$('.form').submit()` here is my iframe and form html

```
<form id="upload_image_form" src="#" target="iframeTarget" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>

<iframe class="iframe" src="<?=url::base()?>user/upload_image/" name="iframeTarget"></iframe>
```

So when i load page i get my iframe load right page but when i submit my form iframe for some reason loads the same page i'm on not the `user/upload_image` why is this happening, maybe my form or iframe is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set your form `action` attribute to `user/upload_image`.

Comment: I think the iframe also need to be outside of the form tags.

Answer (score 1):

Does the iframe id need to also be set to "iframeTarget"?
And i think Dmitry is right, you need an action to post back to. Don't src is needed.